# Paragraph ended before \institute was complete. --can not fix

Tags: titles

I am getting this error while compiling the below code. Also \maketitle is not working.

> Runaway argument? { \at \textsuperscript {1,3}Department of
> Computational Science  ! Paragraph ended before \institute was
> complete.

MWE

```
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Important
%\addbibresource{swa_ref.bib}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

% Insert the name of "your journal" with
\journalname{None}

\title{Some Title}

\author{Author1\textsuperscript{1}\and \textsuperscript{\Letter}~Author2\textsuperscript{2}\and Author3\textsuperscript{3}
        }
\institute{ \at
             \textsuperscript{1,3}Department of Computational Science
          \and
           \at
           \textsuperscript{\Letter}~Corresponding author\\
              \textsuperscript{2}Department of Computer Science \& Engineering
              \email{abc@def.com}
           }
%\date{Drafted:\today}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
To be written later.
\keywords{keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords}
\end{abstract}

%\input{introduction}
%\input{implementation}
%\input{evaluation}
%\input{casestudy}
%\input{conclusion}
% Authors must disclose all relationships or interests that
% could have direct or potential influence or impart bias on
% the work:
%
\section*{Conflict of interest}
 The authors declare that they have no conflict of interest.
%\printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the empty line before `\and`, this tries to start a new paragraph which is not allowed within the `\institute` command.

Comment: The other error is probably because the macro `\Letter` is not defined. So either define it or replace it with something else (maybe `a`?).

Comment: \Letter was displaying a small envelope using the same set of packages in my other document.

Comment: But you should check that the code you post here doesn't have errors unrelated to your question, we don't have your original document

Comment: In OP I have mentioned that \maketitle is also not working. I have modified the MWE as per the suggestion. The paragraph related error is solved but maketitle is still giving error. I have included all the packages from that document, only removed the body text. You will be able to reproduce the same error at your end using the present MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `\maketitle` work add `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}` to your MWE for the sign `\Letter`.

[image: zz]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%Important
%\addbibresource{swa_ref.bib}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
%Table packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}

\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% Insert the name of "your journal" with
\journalname{None}

\title{Some Title}

\author{Author1\textsuperscript{1}\and \textsuperscript{\Letter}~Author2\textsuperscript{2}\and Author3\textsuperscript{3}
}

\institute{\at
    \textsuperscript{1,3}Department of Computational Science
    \and
    \at \textsuperscript{\Letter}~Corresponding author\\
    \textsuperscript{2}Department of Computer Science \& Engineering
    \email{abc@def.com} 
}

\date{Drafted:\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        To be written later.
        \keywords{keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords \and keywords}
    \end{abstract}
    
    %\input{introduction}
    %\input{implementation}
    %\input{evaluation}
    %\input{casestudy}
    %\input{conclusion}
    % Authors must disclose all relationships or interests that
    % could have direct or potential influence or impart bias on
    % the work:
    %
    \section*{Conflict of interest}
    The authors declare that they have no conflict of interest.
    %\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanx Simon, It solved the problem.